# Notify clients on Web API error with SignalR

Tags: rest, api, signalr

I have this Windows Service that calls WebApi service method. On Exception thrown in this method I need to notify part(or all) of my MVC Clients. All three(Windows  Service project,WEB API project, MVC project) projects are under same solution on same server. Is this possible with SignalR or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Windows service and MVC client can be understood and Signalr will work for same.
WebApi to webapi notify is somewhat confusing unless those are two differently hosted (at least different port or webapp) there is not need to use signalr there.